# Голубь и желоб?

Tags: этимология

Можно ли отнести слова голубь и желоб к этимологически однокоренным, исходя из:

1. Исторического писания слова голуб**ь** без мягкого знака на конце, как "голуб";
2. Чередования согласных у->о (с**у**хой -> выс**о**хнуть, д**у**х (в значении дуновения) -> взд**о**хнуть);
3. чередования согласных го -> же (**го**ни -> **же**ни, **го**рло -> **же**рло)

Comment: Заменить бы в этом вопросе голубя залетного на глубь глубокую...

Comment: @guaranteen это была шутка?

Comment: Это шутка, но только по форме. А если по сути замечания, то она в том, что слова желоб-голубь созвучны по чистой случайности. Другое дело желоб-глубь. В этой паре можно отыскать "родственные связи".

Answer (score 1):

В этимологии никогда не *исходят* из похожести, на неё обращают внимание лишь при существовании доказательств исторического использования слова с конкретным значением. Мне "голубь" кажется больше похожим на "прорубь", но этимологически это ровно ничего не значит. Если вы займётесь китайским языком, то сразу увидите десятки слов с *одинаковым* произношением - там никому и в голову не приходит из похожести прочтения выводить родственные связи слов.

Comment: Какой из трёх пунктов моего вопроса говорит о похожести?

Comment: в китайском никому и в голову не приходит мысль о необходимости алфавита, Вы предлагаете отказаться также от него и в русском?

Comment: голуби живут в желобах

Comment: Второй и третий пункты у вас - о _похожести_ рассматриваемой пары на слова, в корнях которых чередуются гласные и согласные звуки и буквы.